Auto Rig Pro: Mirror weight maps through vertex groups
In Auto Rig Pro, I modified the weight maps of the vertex group leg_stretch.l, and I want to mirror them over to leg_stretch.r.

What I tried to do is to duplicate the vertex group.
Vertex Group Menu -> Duplicate Vertex Group

Then tried to mirror the vertex group
Vertex Group Menu -> Mirror Vertex Group

It gave me this weird outcome:

I also tried Vertex Group Menu -> Mirror Vertex Group (Topology)
but it didn't do anything.
